# Dynamic root layout in App Router. NextJS 14.0.1

Tags: next.js, app-router

**TLDR;**
How can I dynamically layout root based on `searchParams`?

**Scenario**
I have `subdomain.domain.com` which will load the landing page. If I scan a QR code that returns the url as `subdomain.domain.com?id=123` then the browser should load a fairly different UI than the landing page, except for the same Header and Footer.
I want to keep both of them as SSR.

**How can I achieve this?**

---

My Background

I am completely new to web development roughly 3 weeks, and I have never done a single web page :P. To sum up my 11 years career roadmap, it was always mobile development (Java Android -> Kotlin Android -> Swift iOS -> JS React Native -> Flutter -> Typescript Expo). Recently I got a chance to enthusiastically work on the Web with no necessary predefined Tech Stack. Ideally, the use case is to scan a QR -> extract id -> fetch is id registered and booked -> give client interaction based on response. After researching the Modern Frontend Web stack I felt like it's bloated with options trying to fix problems of bundling/parsing/transpiling/hydration strategies/esm-or-cjs etc that initially Node and us Developers created in the name of DX. In my use case, I really wanted to go with HTMX+tailwind, but because of my other team members I went with something similar to React but "blazingly fast". So I opted into NextJS for SSR

Any ideas, suggestions, advice, or anything that helps the end user UX will be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Leverage [layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts) to wrap `children` with your common header and footer components. Utilize [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) to capture the ID from the URL on the server side. With the ID, perform a [server-side data fetch](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/patterns) to retrieve the necessary data. Conditionally render the appropriate content: show the landing content if no ID, or the content corresponding to the ID.

Answer (score 0):

In the app router in NextJS 13.4+, the layout file in the app folder is shared between all pages so you can set the header and footer (shared with all pages) in there.

If you have any control over the QR code, I would recommend changing the URL to `subdomain.domain.com/123` as it would allow you to use dynamic route which would make your life easier as it would allow you to fetch data based on the route id in the server component directly.

If you can't change it, you can get them in the Page with something like:

```
export default function Page({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
  searchParams?: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined };
}) {
  // Handle logic for searchParams id as undefined or use fetch based on it.
}
```

This would mean that you need to handle the logic to switch between no id or defined id yourself to toggle the page.